# Vuejs: query params are mixed up when switching between pagination links

Tags: vue.js, routes, pagination, vuejs3, vue-router

I have a pagination configured on the server, but I also need to configure it on the client so that I can see the correct query param when I go to the particular pagination link. I also use `Pinia store` to manage the data and `vue-router` for routing. Here’s what I do:

First I add a `currentPage` to the `onMounted` hook so that I can see the starting page number in the url like `http://localhost:3000/recipes?page=1`.

```
onMounted(async () => {
    await storeRecipe.loadRecipesCount();
    await loadRecipes();
    await router.push(currentPage);
});
```

Here `currentPage` is the current page number, where `page` is a reactive object:

```
const page = reactive({
    number: 1,
    size: 3,
});

const currentPage = {
    query: {
        page: page.number,
    },
};
```

For each pagination links like `prev`, `next`, `first`, `last` I add query param in `:to` and `@click` event like this:

```
<router-link :to="{
    query: {
       page: page.number,
           },
    }" 
    class="pagination__btn-next" 
    :class="{ inactive: page.number === totalPages }" 
    @click="toNextPage">
</router-link>
```

And for pagination numbers:

```
<ul class="pagination__list">
  <li class="pagination__item">
     <router-link
         :to="{
            query: {
              page: page.number,
              },
         }"
         class="pagination__link"
         v-for="pageNumber in totalPages"
         :key="pageNumber"
         :class="{ active: pageNumber === page.number }"
         @click="toSpecificPage(pageNumber)">
         {{ pageNumber }}
     </router-link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If I press back button in the browser, the query param `?page=1` disappears and I can only see `http://localhost:3000/recipes` now (I use `createWebHistory` mode).

Then if I press `Next` router-link, I’m already at  `?page=2` (even though there were no query param at all). If I press `Prev` router-link, I’ll move to `?page=3`. So you can see it’s completely mixed up for some reason. And now if I click back button of the browser multiple times, I can see the url changes, but the pagination numbers don’t.
Here's the function for `Next` page link as an example:

```
const toNextPage = async () => {
    page.number++;
    await loadRecipes();
};
```

And the query on the server:

```
if (page && pageSize) {
    const offset = (page - 1) * pageSize;
    const recipes = await pool.query(
        'SELECT * FROM recipe ORDER BY recipe_id LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2',
         [pageSize, offset]
    );
    res.json(recipes.rows);
}
```

Please, give me a solution. (If you need more details, please let me know).